# Android - Up Action Issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin

In my app I skipped the headers in PreferenceActivity following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802640/skip-the-headers-in-preferenceactivity-when-theres-only-one-header#answer-10960720). I would post a comment on this answer but for now I don't have enough reputation so here is the question.

Starting Activity like this:

```
val intent = Intent(this, SettingsActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra(PreferenceActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT, SettingsActivity.GeneralPreferenceFragment::class.java.name)
intent.putExtra(PreferenceActivity.EXTRA_NO_HEADERS, true)
startActivity(intent)
```

In manifest file:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SettingsActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.goranceko.playlearn.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Whole SettingsActivity:

```
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatPreferenceActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setupActionBar()
}

/**
 * Set up the [android.app.ActionBar], if the API is available.
 */
private fun setupActionBar() {
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
}

override fun onMenuItemSelected(featureId: Int, item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    val id = item.itemId
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        if (!super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item)) {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)
        }
        return true
    }
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item)
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
override fun onIsMultiPane(): Boolean {
    return isXLargeTablet(this)
}

/**
 * This method stops fragment injection in malicious applications.
 * Make sure to deny any unknown fragments here.
 */
override fun isValidFragment(fragmentName: String): Boolean {
    return PreferenceFragment::class.java.name == fragmentName
            || GeneralPreferenceFragment::class.java.name == fragmentName
}

/**
 * This fragment shows general preferences only. It is used when the
 * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
class GeneralPreferenceFragment : PreferenceFragment() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("language"))
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("timelimit"))
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val id = item.itemId
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            startActivity(Intent(activity, SettingsActivity::class.java))
            return true
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}

companion object {

    /**
     * A preference value change listener that updates the preference's summary
     * to reflect its new value.
     */
    private val sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener { preference, value ->
        val stringValue = value.toString()

        if (preference is ListPreference) {
            // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
            // the preference's 'entries' list.
            val listPreference = preference
            val index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue)

            // Set the summary to reflect the new value.
            preference.setSummary(
                    if (index >= 0)
                        listPreference.entries[index]
                    else
                        null)

        } else if (preference is RingtonePreference) {

        } else {
            // For all other preferences, set the summary to the value's
            // simple string representation.
            preference.summary = stringValue
        }
        true
    }

    /**
     * Helper method to determine if the device has an extra-large screen. For
     * example, 10" tablets are extra-large.
     */
    private fun isXLargeTablet(context: Context): Boolean {
        return context.resources.configuration.screenLayout and Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE
    }

    /**
     * Binds a preference's summary to its value. More specifically, when the
     * preference's value is changed, its summary (line of text below the
     * preference title) is updated to reflect the value. The summary is also
     * immediately updated upon calling this method. The exact display format is
     * dependent on the type of preference.

     * @see .sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener
     */
    private fun bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(preference: Preference) {
        // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
        preference.onPreferenceChangeListener = sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener

        // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's current value.
        sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
                PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.context)
                        .getString(preference.key, ""))
    }
}
```

}

Here is `R.xml.pref_general`:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ListPreference
    android:defaultValue="@string/pref_language_default"
    android:entries="@array/pref_language_entries"
    android:entryValues="@array/pref_language_values"
    android:key="language"
    android:negativeButtonText="@null"
    android:positiveButtonText="@null"
    android:title="@string/pref_language_title" />

<EditTextPreference
    android:defaultValue="@string/pref_timelimit_default"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:title="@string/pref_timelimit_title"
    android:key="timelimit" />
```

This works flawlessly on `API Level 27`, but for example on `API level 19` I have following issue.

When I go to SettingsActivity it automatically shows GeneralPreferenceFragment, but when i click back (Up Action in Toolbar) it just show blank screen with the same Toolbar. Another click on back button works fine as application shows MainActivity.

It is like I got from Fragment to SettingsActivity with first click and back to MainActivity with another.

I thought it is issue with `PreferenceActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT` and `PreferenceActivity.EXTRA_NO_HEADERS` but both constants are available from `API level 11`.

What did I miss here? Thanks for your time in advance.

**Edit:** Solved my problem simply by changing `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` to `setHasOptionsMenu(false)` in SettingsActivity.

Comment: Settings without headers work for me without the extras. The settins activity xml declares its settings fragment and i start the activity with just `startActivity(Intent(activity, SettingsActivity::class.java))`

Comment: Please, post your code which adds fragment to screen

Comment: @AlexeyDenysenko, I added Fragment Class to question. Is this what you need?

Comment: @GoranČeko no, you can just add `SettingsActivity` code and I will found what I need

Comment: @AlexeyDenysenko, Added whole SettingsActivity to post.

Comment: Please add `R.xml.pref_general`, also

Comment: @AlexeyDenysenko, Done, thank you for your effort.